# Symmetric matrix and multiplication

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

V be the vector space of $11\times 11$ real symmetric matrix such that it is closed under multiplication . Then what is the dimension of V ?

Comment: Do you mean V is spanned by products of symmetric matrices?

Comment: Hint: symmetric matrices being closed under multiplication means that for any two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB=(AB)^T$.

Comment: @jobe Which is usually wrong for arbitrary symmetric matrices. The constraint means they must be commuting matrices.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, that is exactly what my hint is saying. I just did not want to be so explicit, letting the person asking the question figuring it out by him/herself. I thought it would be clear that I am referencing "symmetric matrices closed under multiplication", not arbitrary symmetric matrices.